PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; Spring Boot Test issue
Trying to run following script before my testcase using @SpringbootTest
I refer to this script with my @Sql tag
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SA."TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT
ON "SA"."FOO"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    nextval NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT FOO_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
    INTO nextval
    FROM dual;
    :new.ID_FOO := nextval;
END;

this script works in SQL Developer, but not in my Spring project:
following error

Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 68, Sql = BEGIN SELECT
FOO_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO nextval FROM dual, OriginalSql
= BEGIN SELECT FOO_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO nextval FROM dual, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 1, column 69: PLS-00103: Encountered
the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
;
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)


Your edit fundamentally changes the nature of the problem/solution - my answer on why it is happening is probably still relevant but there may be a more appropriate domain-specific solution for Spring Boot Test (rather than just a generic Oracle/JDBC solution). I've added the appropriate tags to the question so that hopefully you get more relevant answers.


Trying to run following script before my testcase

In Oracle, a command can only contain a single statement (this helps to prevent SQL injection attacks).
If you are passing the entire script using JDBC then it will not split the script into individual statements and would send everything to the database; at which point, the database tries to parse the input as a single statement and fails (because you have multiple statements).
Split the script up into individual statements and send them one-by-one to the database.
To do that:

The SQL statement terminator is either ; or / on a blank line.
The PL/SQL statement terminator is / on a blank line.

Edit your script so that after every SQL statement there is a / on a blank line after the statement (and no ; after the statement) and then both SQL and PL/SQL statements will have a single, consistent statement terminator. Then you can just split the script into statements looking for \n/\n and send everything in between as individual statements (do not include the statement terminator in what you send).
Note: This assumes you will not have string literals that contain / on an empty line in your script - if you can have that edge case then you will need a more robust parser.

Thanks for your solution. For my project personally I had to hard declare this seperator, otherwise it did not recognised it as one.
So I added this to my application.yaml file under its spring: parent : sql: init: separator: /;  so my seperator is equal to /;.
Now I just had to add this /; at the very end of my .sql script.
